# PyQt threads- run same thread over and over

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qthread

If I have a function that calls a thread, and I connect that function to a button , can I call the same thread multiple times by clicking the button several times? I ask because I have a thread that creates folder with sub folders and when I do it over and over there is a delay in folder creation until I restart gui and run again, they will get created. I use the thread to keep the gui from freezing.

Comment: Keep in mind that due to the dreaded [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) only one of these threads will be running at one time no matter how many you spawn.

Comment: How else would you call a function without the gui freezing until it’s finished?

Comment: Well, there is a possibility of using [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) instead if you want detached threads that can actually run in parallel (so long as you have multiple cores) but even Python threads are enough for many tasks, I was just informing you that you need to be aware of how they work and where a delay might be coming from. Without presenting what you're actually performing in your threads we cannot tell you more than that.

Comment: The thread I am using calls a program via cmd prompt then runs a loop until it throws an error for it to end then spits an output file out, once done it will create a folder and put files the program outputs inside of it

Comment: I updated the post with the code I am using, i'm just unsure how to go on about running commands simultaneously.

Comment: So you're wondering why you're experiencing delays after running several threads that each calls subprocesses all the time? That's a horrendously inefficient way to do what you're attempting to do. For starters, explore the [WIN32API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of trying to find an error dialog through the CLI `tasklist.exe` - you can see an example at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44058799)...

Comment: Yes, would mutliprocessing cut out the delays I’m seeing? Or is using the thread the way I am doing it, incorrect?

Comment: It wouldn't improve much as the blunt of the work happens outside of your process. You should re-think your whole process flow not to rely on so many external calls.

Comment: Okay, by external calls you mean stuff I’m checking for? Like if file exists or if task is running?

Comment: Yes. Do not do it so frequently and use Win32 API whenever possible. Try to think of another way to achieve your task because, as I said, what you're attempting is horribly inefficient.