# How to check if a process is running in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am doing a program that prevents certain applications from opening.
But it uses a lot of CPU.
Because the program is always trying to terminate that application. I want this program to use less of the CPU. How can I do this?

**PS**: *I could not reach this result for 2 hours.*

*My Python Version : **3.6.3***

**I don't want any 3rd party modules.**

My code that uses a lot of CPU:

```
si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
si.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
while True:
    subprocess.call("taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe", startupinfo=si)
    subprocess.call("taskkill /F /IM opera.exe", startupinfo=si)
    subprocess.call("taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe", startupinfo=si)
    subprocess.call("taskkill /F /IM firefox.exe", startupinfo=si)
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: Use Win32API to periodically obtain the task list, search for it and kill the desired processes if they show up. You can see an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44008243/tasklist-command-with-description/44058799#44058799) (the last example, sans the step of obtaining the task details).

Comment: I don't want any **3rd party modules.**

Comment: Then use the first example from the aforementioned answer to obtain the task list, and then sift through it. It will be slower, tho, but at least you won't be creating 4 subprocesses all the time.

Comment: Leaving aside how malicious that code looks - have you considered just configuring the OS to not allow those programs using UAC or uninstalling them?

Comment: Python, on its own without external “powers”, cannot do this. Also, that code uses a lot of CPU because it is [busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) and even worse spawning subprocesses every second. That is obviously bringing your computer to its knees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on no 3rd party modules (and I'd argue that win32api when running on Windows should be shipped with Python anyway), you can at least offset most of the work to systems that do utilize Win32 API instead of trying to do everything through Python. Here's how I'd do it:

```
import subprocess
import time

# list of processes to auto-kill
kill_list = ["chrome.exe", "opera.exe", "iexplore.exe", "firefox.exe"]

# WMI command to search & destroy the processes
wmi_command = "wmic process where \"{}\" delete\r\n".format(
    " OR ".join("Name='{}'".format(e) for e in kill_list))

# run a single subprocess with Windows Command Prompt
proc = subprocess.Popen(["cmd.exe"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    proc.stdin.write(wmi_command.encode("ascii"))  # issue the WMI command to it
    proc.stdin.flush()  # flush the STDIN buffer
    time.sleep(1)  # let it breathe a little
```

In most cases you won't even notice the performance impact of this one.

Now, why would you need such a thing in the first place is a completely different topic - I'd argue that there is no real-world use for a script like this.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is faster to use psutil:

```
import psutil

for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if process.name() == 'myprocess':
        process.kill()
```